# Cannot mount Samba share: Unable to find suitable address

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I just moved house, and after putting up all my devices, on my RasPi, running Raspbian, I cannot mount my TimeCapsule's SMB file shares anymore. It used to simply work, but Now I get this:

```
root@pi:/home/pi# mount -t cifs //timecapsule.local/SomeDrive /media/SomeDrive/ -o username=myuser,sec=ntlm
Password:
Unable to find suitable address.
```

I cannot even list the shares with smbclient. This also fails. The kern.log shows these messages:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

I can ping the TimeCapsule, and I can mount the shares from OS X via AFP. However SMB does not work either, I get an error that it. I haven't changed any configuration, only the wiring. How can I check if the SMB is running on the TimeCapsule (which port)? Could it still be the Pi's fault?

Comment: Actually, I haven't changed the wiring on that part. The Pi is still connected via copper to the TimeCapsule. So no other router or anything in between...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel very stupid. I rebooted the TimeCapsule and now it works. "Did you try turning it off and on again" was the solution.

The reason was probably this: I switched the IP network range of my router from 192.168.178.0 to 192.168.1.0, so that the smbd on the TC probably got confused...